# Finding Mincuts / max flow for a graph

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I have generated a graph from an image and the algorithm I am working on demands finding the min cut in the graph. But as per my understanding some nodes - source and sink, needs to be attached to the graph before applying any standard algorithm for finding the same.On what basis should I attach them and where??....I have done lot of reading on this but none specifies about this.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what have you read, but usually authors clearly specify what should be treated as source and sink.

Consider binary segmentation. 
(image taken from [here](http://bitsearch.blogspot.ru/2014/01/understanding-graph-cuts-for-image.html), more information can also be found there)
[image]

O and B stand for object and background respectively, so you can think of correspondence between terminals and labels.

To clarify further:

- image pixels are represented by nodes
- links can be of 2 types - terminal links and neighbour links
- terminal links have a cost that shows how similar are nodes(pixels) to terminal(label model)
- neighbour links show how nodes(pixels) are similar to nodes(pixels), that are connected with this link.

This is only one example of applying graph cut to images, there are more: multi-level segmentation, depthmap estimation, etc, where nodes and edges may have different meanings. I strongly suggest you to get more familiar with literature first, since it will help you to adapt the approaches you want to use to your needs.

Comment: As mentioned in the above figure should the terminal nodes be augmented or are they some pixels from the image itself??

Comment: They are not pixels. Do you use your own implementation or some other?

Comment: I want to use my own. But I am confused with the source and sink nodes and the edges(values) they have with other nodes. Can you suggest some readings related to that?